# Nginx error pages not working

Tags: nginx

I have the following vhost entry

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    #access_log   /var/log/nginx/nginx-access.log;

    location  /media/ {
    root /home/luke/django/solentcms;
     }

    location  /admin/media/ {
    root /home/luke/virts/django1.25/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media;
     }

    location / {
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
            root    /home/luke/django/solentcms/404;
            allow   all;
     }


    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
            root    /home/luke/django/solentcms/404;
            allow   all;
     }
```

}

However, 404's and 50x errors are still be re-directed to the horrible nginx default pages.Any ideas as to why? This syntax works on one of my other servers.

Answer (score 2):

You need this:
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_intercept_errors

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's due to the `error_page` lines coming after `location /` in the configuration file.  That block is proxying all requests back to whatever is on port 8001.

Try putting them earlier in the `server` block and see if that works.